# Frequently 'Not charging', Ubuntu 22.04 on Thinkpad X1 Carbon

Tags: power-management, lenovo, battery, thinkpad, charging

I have a Thinkpad X1 Carbon laptop and installed Ubuntu 22.04 LTS on it. It is quite weird that almost every day before properly charging this laptop, I have to go to bios and disable the battery (reset power management I guess?). Although it does detect if the power cable has been plugged, it shows 'not charging'. I have tried to update firmware and the bios but that didn't help.